# PowerShell Module Test-NetworkConnection: Suppress Status Output

Tags: powershell

I have written a small PowerShell script that uses the Test-NetworkConnection module to test a series of network connections.

Unfortunately, the PowerShell module displays status messages in the foreground, which overlay the program output of my script.

I have already added "| Out-Null" after the module call, but this does not suppress the messages.

How can I prevent these status messages from being displayed when the PowerShell module is called?
[PowerShell Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GcTx.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is `Write-Progress` output. You can suppress it by setting preference variable:
`$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'`

Comment: Yes, this worked.

Many Thanks!